# Java: Error when save file in Resource after Deployment

Tags: java, deployment, resources

My program has a function that read/write file from resource. This function I have tested smoothly.
For example, I write something to file, restart and loading again, I can read that data again.

But after I export to jar file, I faced problems when write file. Here is my code to write file:

```
URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource("/resource/data.sav");
File file = new File(resourceUrl.toURI());
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream( output);
```

When this code run, I has notice error in Command Prompt: 
[image: my error]
So, My data cannot saved. (I know it because after I restarted app, nothing changed !!!)

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: Couldn't you have copied that stacktrace and pasted as text instead?

Comment: I think that the main issue is that in development you are writing to a real file, while in "production" everything is jar'ed up and your ressources is a file in a jar that you can't write to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't write files into a jar file this way. The URI you get from `getResource()` isn't a  `file:///` URI, and it can't be passed to `java.io.File's` constructor. The only way to write a zip file is by using the classes in `java.util.zip` that are designed for this purpose, and those classes are designed to let you write entire jar files, not stream data to a single file inside of one. In a real installation, the user may not even have permission to write to the jar file, anyway.

You're going to need to save your data into a real file on the file system, or possibly, if it's small enough, by using the preferences API.

Comment: Can you tell me more about `java.util.zip`. you mean that i unzip file and write and unpack again ?

Comment: Well, what I really meant was you give up the idea of updating the jar file altogether. As I said, your program may not even have proper permissions to do so. Save your data someplace else!

Answer (score -2):

You need to read/write file as an input stream to read from jar file.

```
public static String getValue(String key)
    {
        String _value = null;
        try 
        {
            InputStream loadedFile = ConfigReader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configFileName);
            if(loadedFile == null) throw new Exception("Error: Could not load the file as a stream!");
            props.load(loadedFile);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            try {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                props.load(new FileInputStream(configFileName));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                ExceptionWriter.LogException(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                ExceptionWriter.LogException(e);
            }
        }
        _value =  props.getProperty(key);
        if(_value == null || _value.equals("")) System.out.println("Null value supplied for key: "+key);
        return _value;
    }
```

Comment: getResourceAsStream() will help read the file, I agree -- but he won't be able to write to the file, and so a completely different approach is needed anyway